# .submit() Prevents Form from Submitting

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a fairly simple form and ViewModel which works fine, but when I add this JS, the form no longer submits to the controller:

```
$("#crmtForm").submit(function (e) {
    console.log('submit');
});
```

Why? I'm pretty sure this is supposed to work... Please can someone help this makes no sense.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(CRMTItemViewModel viewModel)
{
    viewModel.CreatedBy = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "name").Value;
    if (viewModel.ProjectTitle == "spinnertest")
        return View();

    // Insert db rows?
    var crmtItem = await crmtItemsManager.InsertItem(viewModel);

    // Initialise workspace on a seperate thread
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        var projectManager = new ProjectManager();
        projectManager.ProcessRequest(crmtItem);
    }).Start();

    // Redirect to item
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = crmtItem.Id });
}
```

**Form**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "CrmtItems", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "crmtForm" }))
{
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>New Project Workspace Form</h4>
    <hr />


    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectTitle, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectTitle, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectTitle, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectStage, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.ProjectStage, new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectStage, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CRMTNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CRMTNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CRMTNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GbSNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GbSNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GbSNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Confidential, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Confidential, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "height:17px;" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Confidential, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.SelectedTags, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id, new { required = "required" })
            @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedTags, new SelectList(users, "UserName", "DisplayName"), new { @class = "teamSelecter", name = "states[]", multiple = "multiple", style = "display:none; width:100%;", required = "required" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedTags, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <p id="pmWarning" class="text-danger" hidden>Please select one or more project managers</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br />
    <button id="formSubmit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg pull-right" type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
    <div class="loader pull-right" hidden></div>

</div>
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class CRMTItemViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Project Title")]
    [Remote("DoesProjectTitleExist", "CRMTItems", HttpMethod = "POST", 
        ErrorMessage = "Workspace for that project title already exists.")]
    public string ProjectTitle { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Project Stage")]
    public ProjectStage? ProjectStage { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "CRMT Number")]
    [Remote("DoesCrmtNumberExist", "CRMTItems", HttpMethod = "POST",
        ErrorMessage = "Workspace for that CRMT number already exists.")]
    public int? CRMTNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "GBS Number")]
    [Remote("DoesGbSNumberExist", "CRMTItems", HttpMethod = "POST", 
        ErrorMessage = "Workspace for that GBS project number already exists.")]
    public int? GbSNumber { get; set; }

    public bool Confidential { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Project Managers")]
    public IEnumerable<string> SelectedTags { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Not related, but you should delete all your `required = "required"` attributes, and add a `[Required]` attribute to your properties, and include the scripts for client side validation

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your comment Stephen. By 'client side valudation scripts' do you mean e.g. the `DoesProjectTitleExist` controllers etc?

Comment: No, I mean add the `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` scripts

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am just using the default validate scripts (`v1.17.0 ` validate and `v3.2.10` unobtrusive), but I also added `$.validator.setDefaults({
            ignore: ''
        });` in my _layout so that it works with `select2`

Comment: Do you have any error in your JavaScript? I mean if you open Dev tools and submit the form, do you see any error in the browser dev tools?

Comment: @Hooman There are no errors

Comment: @Bassie, In that case, you definitely need to remove those attributes since they do nothing at all (`jquery.validate.js` adds the `novalidate` attribute to your form). Currently you have no client side validation and no server side validation

Comment: @StephenMuecke But my form is being validated, in that if I don't fill those fields in a message appears telling me it needs a value. The `Remote` attributes are also working as expected (they check the db for existing rows with the same value). In fact apart from not submitting when using the `submit` handler, the form works perfectly. I will remove those attributes and try though

Comment: That is not possible (check the html of your `<form>` element - you should see a `novalidate="novalidate"` attribute (which disables HTML-5 validation due to the conflicts it causes with `jquery.validate`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm not sure what to say because it is definitely validating as I described. However, removing the `required` attributes seems to have fixed the not-submitting issue! You should add an answer

Comment: My form looks like

`<form action="/CrmtItems/Create" id="crmtForm" method="post"><div class="form-horizontal">`

Comment: Then there is something odd going on (just not sure what yet)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171952/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-bassie).

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code in my project its working,may be issue with your jquery version,one more thing I found when I was created scaffolding view with this model it automatically created `@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}` at end of view page,
when I removed this script from page then able to call post method otherwise not.